# Reference previous column

Tags: python, pandas

I am looping through every other column of a dataframe comparing that value to the previous columns in a new column but I can't seem to reference correctly the previous column. I tried using shift but it doesn't seem to work on columns.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 4),columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
for x in df.ix[:, 1::2]:

    df['Diff']=df[x]<df.index[x-1]

print (df)
```

Comment: looping through every other column

Comment: why are you using `.ix`?

Comment: show us the expected output

Comment: to reference the column, I know its not used anymore but it works for now @Yuca

Comment: a new column with true or false values comparing every even column and their previous column  @W-B

Comment: but you have more than one comparison, you need multiple columns or a list in one column?

Comment: @Yuca df['Diff'] is the new column comparing an even column with its previous

Comment: I know, but you have 4 columns, hence diff is only going to show the difference of D and C, and you will not know about B and A

Comment: @Yuca columns 2 & 4 are referenced by the for loop, from there I am trying to grab the previous column so for 2 it would col2>1 for column 4 col4>3 and so on

Comment: I know you're going to loop through them, but you're overwriting the contents of diff on every loop, do you understand that?

Comment: for x in df.columns[1::2]:  
    count=count+1
    df[str(count)]=df.iloc[:,df.columns.get_loc(x)] - df.iloc[:,df.columns.get_loc(x)-1]

Comment: I fixed it by just appending a string counting value to it to the column name

Comment: thank you @Yuca for your help

Comment: yeah, my question was how do you want to store it, because you could create multiple columns or store multiple values in one column :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping it as close to your logic as possible:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 4),columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
for x in df.columns[1::2]:    
    print(df.iloc[:,df.columns.get_loc(x)] < df.iloc[:,df.columns.get_loc(x)-1])
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this?

```
for i in range(1, df.shape[1]):
    df['diff'] = df[df.columns[i]] < df[df.columns[i-1]]
```